# Update DataGridView (format) updates from worker thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-interface, datagridview

I have a C# WinForms application that I am playing with to refresh my windows dev skills, that required DataGridView row format and tooltip updates to trigger as the result of calculations performed in a worker thread...

ie.

```
// -----------------------
// CODE FROM MAIN PROCESING THREAD
// -----------------------
foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridRow in dataGridView_TableList.Rows)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessGridRow, new object[]{/* row data passed here */});
}
```

```
// -----------------------
// WORKER THREAD CODE
// -----------------------
private void ProcessGridRow(object state)
{
    object[] array = state as object[];
    int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(array[0]);
    /* extract remaining row data here */
    /* perform operations based on row data */

    // PERFORM ROW FORMATTING UPDATES
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView_TableList.Rows[rowIndex];
    row.Cells[<SOME_COL_NAME>].ToolTipText = "new tooltip based on performed operations";
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        cell.Style.BackColor = <SOME COLOR>;
        cell.Style.SelectionBackColor = <SOME COLOR>;
    }
    dataGridView_TableList.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { dataGridView_TableList.Refresh(); }));
}
```

My threads are performing a heap of disk operations based on the datagrid row content, so I can see that they are completing successfully ... based on updated file content and log messages, however the code after `// PERFORM ROW FORMATTING UPDATES` does not result in updates to my `DataGridView` - but does work if this code is structured to be single threaded.

EDIT:
I added a:

```
dataGridView_TableList.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { 
    dataGridView_TableList.Refresh(); }));
```

By then moving this code into the Form shown callback I'm getting the effect I want.

Comment: You cannot create, access, or modify any UI element from a non-UI thread. You can marshall data to another thread and return data to the UI thread and then have it update your actual UI.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding a:

```
dataGridView_TableList.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { dataGridView_TableList.Refresh(); }));
```

And then moving this code into the Form shown callback I'm getting the effect I want.